# I have still rake/rdoctask deprecated warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, warnings, deprecated

I've made bundle update a now I have still rake/rdoctask deprecated warning after running rake command.

```
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /home/cheetah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@tobiska/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
```

I tried to read this tip http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-fix-rake-rdoctask-is-deprecated-use-rdoc-task-instead-1169.html but my Rakefile is OK.

I have no idea, how to solve this problem. Any tips? Thanks a lot.

Martin

Comment: I'm still battling this issue with a number of projects. With all the obvious things taken care of (rdoc etc) it is still bugging me. I strongly suspect some gems in the project .. but tracking the issue down is a problem. Does anyone know how to get ruby/rake to report the precise code location of whatever caused the WARNING?

Answer (score 19):

You can have multiple versions of rake on your system and you can view them by running

```
$ gem list
=> rake
```

(0.9.2.2, 0.9.2, 0.8.7)
To define a version in my project, define it in the Gemfile as

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

then run

```
bundle update rake
```

Your project version is now as specified in the Gemfile and your WARNING is now gone.

Comment: I do not have multiple versions of rake.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to change Gemfile and run 'bundle update rake' need run for me too:

```
gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.2.2
gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.2
gem install rake -v 0.8.7
```

Answer (score 3):

In some projects that don't invoke the entire rails stack, adding rdoc to the Gemfile was the key to success for me:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2.2'
  gem "rdoc", '~> 3.12'
end
```

UPDATE: This was still bugging me with a rails 3.0.x project. Rakefile, gems all seemed ok but I was still getting the issue. To find out exactly where the warning wacoming from I put a canary in gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:

```
if Rake.application
  begin
    raise 'where am i'                                                                
  rescue                                                                       
    puts $@                                                                    
  end 
  Rake.application.deprecate('require \'rake/rdoctask\'', 'require \'rdoc/task\' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)', __FILE__)
end
```

This immediately pointed to the issue in the rails stack itself. A quick check and it is apparent that rails 3.0.8 is full of requires to rake/rdoctask. Updating to rails (3.0.9 or higher I believe) fixes the issue (or you can downgrade rake as others have suggested).

But while you are stuck on ~ 3.0.8 and don't want to downgrade rake, you can suppress the warning by setting ignore_deprecate in your Rakefile:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'

# add this (and perhaps make it conditional on Rails.version if you like):
Rake.application.options.ignore_deprecate = true

Babylon::Application.load_tasks
```

Why suppress the warning? My main motivation was to ensure cron jobs that invoke rake don't log and email spurious output.

Comment: yeah, its come back to bug me too. The rdoc trick takes care of one cause, but there are others...

Comment: ok now I'm happy: got a solution that's working. (updating my answer accordingly)