# Ruby on Rails: Error message when running rake commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

whenever I run a rake task on the command line I get this error message:

> 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
>       at /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
>   WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
>       ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
>   WARNING: DSL method Billings::Application#task called at /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
>   Loaded suite /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader

Can anybody tell me how to get rid of this?

Comment: Did you search SO first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993162/i-have-still-rake-rdoctask-deprecated-warning

And there's plenty of others

Answer (score 0):

How about generating a new app in another directory an copy the Rakefile? If the problem persists, it may be a problem of your custom rake tasks or some of your gems/plugins.

Comment: I have already generated a number of apps but I keep getting the same error whenever I run a rake task.

Comment: OK, I fixed it by deinstalling my rake 0.8.7 gem using this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199301/global-access-to-rake-dsl-methods-is-deprecated